# PUT request using ASIHTTP?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, rest, asihttprequest

I have a web-service which is using PUT method to request from the URL default/isUserInternational/id/1 and in the request body should append isInternational=1.

I'm using following code and still I could not make PUT request.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"default/isUserInternational/id/%@", @"5"]];
self.asiFormDataRequest = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[self.asiFormDataRequest setDelegate:self];
[self.asiFormDataRequest setTimeOutSeconds:REQUEST_TIMEOUT];
[self.asiFormDataRequest setPostFormat:ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat];
[self.asiFormDataRequest setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];
[self.asiFormDataRequest addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
[self.asiFormDataRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];

//[self.asiFormDataRequest addRequestHeader:@"1" value:@"isInternational"];
//[self.asiFormDataRequest appendPostData:[@"1" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[self.asiFormDataRequest addPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"isInternational"];
[self.asiFormDataRequest startSynchronous];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although If you used appendPostData: or appendPostDataFromFile: it wont work. Plus if you used them and it will considers as POST request as mentioned in the documentation.

// Default becomes POST when you use appendPostData: / appendPostDataFromFile: / setPostBody:

( http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#setting_request_headers).

So Im posting correct code which has worked for me, hope it might helpful for others!

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"default/isUserInternational/id/%@", @"5"]];
self.asiFormDataRequest = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[self.asiFormDataRequest setDelegate:self];
[self.asiFormDataRequest setTimeOutSeconds:REQUEST_TIMEOUT];
//[self.asiFormDataRequest setPostFormat:ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat];
[self.asiFormDataRequest addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
[self.asiFormDataRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
[self.asiFormDataRequest addRequestHeader:@"1" value:@"isInternational"];
[self.asiFormDataRequest setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];

[self.asiFormDataRequest addPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"isInternational"];
[self.asiFormDataRequest startSynchronous];
```

AND REMEMBER to remove the line [self.asiFormDataRequest setPostFormat:ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat]; as it makes your request to be considered as a POST. That was silly mistake of mine!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data via PUT, use `appendPostData:` or `appendPostDataFromFile:` .

Comment: Thank you for your answer and but it did not work for me. Please refer my answer as I corrected my silly mistake in there.